# How to find if my Photoshop CS6 has Retina support

Tags: macos, display, adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to tell if my Photoshop supports retina?

If I find it's out of date with that feature, how do I update and make sure it went thrught?

Comment: Why not open the app and if it looks blurry it doesn't support Retina?

Comment: Beacosue I do not own one, planning to buy it. Want to sort software first before jumping in to new display. Opening is not answering out of date and update assurance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop CS6 supports retina since version 13.0.3.
There is a [blog article](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2013/01/retina-display-support-and-photoshop-cs6.html) from Adobe about this

How to update Photoshop:
1. In Photoshop, choose Help > Updates.
2. The Adobe Application Manager will launch. Select Adobe Photoshop CS6 and choose Update.

How to confirm that the Update worked
1. In Photoshop, choose Photoshop > About Photoshop (Mac)
2. For Mac perpetual customers, the version at the top should be Version: 13.0.3
3. For Win/Mac Creative Cloud members, the version at the top should be Version: 13.1.1